# "Roger was asking for help to heavens" is wrong sentence?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, sentence-meaning

I'm not a native but I'm working as a writer, writing American gossip news. My boss told me that "Roger was asking for help to heavens." is a wrong sentence. What is wrong with it and what's the correct phrase? Because I've subscribed to grammarly and it didn't find any mistake on the grammar. Thanks before.

Comment: *Ask* does not take the infinitive *to*. However, when the intended meaning requires, it can take *from*.  Your options are "Roger was **asking the heavens** for help." and "Roger was asking for help **from** the heavens." HTH.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: I see now, that makes sense. Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Add a determiner “*the* heavens”, and it might *just* work if Roger was a trainee pilot asking for help with flying.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! As Kris points out, [the English Language Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) is a brilliant resource and may be worth your time. Since you state you're working as a writer, [the Writing Stack Exchange](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) may also be worth taking a look at.

Comment: @Lawrence that made me laugh XD but no, Roger is not a trainee pilot.

Comment: @ALambentEye thank you I might just check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the verb 'ask' with the preposition 'to' is not correct in this context.  'Ask' and its synonyms include the meaning of addressing another person.
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ask

Use a different verb which does not necessarily include addressing another person.

Examples:

"Roger cried for help to the heavens."
"Roger shouted for help to the heavens."

A more natural way to say this would be:

"Roger cried to the heavens for help."

If you're going to use a verb like 'ask', 'beg', or 'request' or 'demand', you would say:

"Roger asked for help from the heavens."
"Roger begged for help from the heavens."
"Roger requested help from the heavens."
"Roger demanded help from the heavens."

Comment: I see. Thank you for the help. I really appreciate it. <3

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  English is tricky irregular language.  I recommend reading fiction in English as much as possible so you can see examples and become accustomed to them.